# Python iterate through dictionary x amount of times?

Tags: python

I have an array of colors. I want the program to 'paint' a page, move to the next page, 'paint' another page the next color in the array, repeatedly 10 times.

However, there seems to be a bug in the code below. My code will iterate through the colors on the same page WITHOUT turning/moving to the next page. Hence I end up with several pages of the same color.

```
for x in range(10):
    for i in colors:
       turnPage()
       paint(i)
```

```
What the program will do is
Blue
Red
Green
turnPage()
#page ends up green
Blue
Red
Green
TurnPage()
#page ends up green

But I want the output to be
Blue
turnPage()
Red
turnPage()
Green 
turnPage()
```

EDIT: Edits and adding full code below for reference/clarification.

```
colors = ['ff5733', '5271FF', 'CB6CE6']
#Starting with 2, page 1 was unique and was painted before the loop
for x in (number+2 for number in range(5)):

    for i in colors:
        #Using selenium to move to next page
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/section[3]/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div""" % x)))

        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 10, 10).click().perform()

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="__id17"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"""))).click()

        #Using selenium to change page color, i
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/input"""))).send_keys(i)
```

Comment: Please post more details. It's hard to help you without knowing what's going on or what your code looks like

Comment: No idea what `turnPage()`, `colors` or `paint()` is. How are we supposed to help you? You need to provide a [mre]

Comment: What do you mean with "I have a dictionary of colors". Are the colors the dictionary's keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [generators](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) for this:

```py
def turnpage():
    print("turned")

def generator(colors):
    while True:
        for color in colors:
            yield color

colors = ["green","red","blue"]

gen = generator(colors)

for page_number in range(10):
    print(next(gen))
    turnpage()
```

Output:

```
green 
turned
red
turned
blue
turned
green 
turned
red
turned
blue
turned
green 
turned
red
turned
blue
turned
green 
turned
```